# Vaadin ColorPicker IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, vaadin

I have downloaded the Vaadin Colorpicker addon to try it out  ,  there is a small problem if i klick the colorPicker "Button"  twice  i get an IllegalArgumentException :

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window was already added to application - it can not be added to another window also.
    at com.vaadin.ui.Window.addWindow(Window.java:1447)
    at com.vaadin.addon.colorpicker.ColorPicker.changeVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1299)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1219)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:735)
```

Another question :

I want the colorPicker window to popup if I click on an item in a Menu  something like if i click on "set Color" i get the colorPicker window.  its quite hard to place the button on my GUI :P

EDIT :

Im adding the ColorPicker like this :

```
    colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
    colorPicker.setButtonCaption("Set Color");
    colorPicker.setRGBVisibility(false);
    colorPicker.setHSVVisibility(false);
    colorPicker.setHistoryVisibility(false);
    colorPicker.addListener(this);
    window.addComponent(colorPicker);
```

Comment: Can you post how you are adding the color picker in your code?

Comment: @Terrell Plotzki Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try this code in your application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        Window mainWindow = new Window("Your Application");

        // Create a color picker
        ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker("ColorPicker", Color.RED);

        // Add a color change listener to the color picker
        cp.addListener(new ColorPicker.ColorChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void colorChanged(ColorChangeEvent event) {
                MyApplication.this.getMainWindow()
                .showNotification("Color changed!");
            }
        });

        mainWindow.addComponent(cp);
        setMainWindow(mainWindow);
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work, then there is a defect in ColorPicker (and you could report a defect here: http://dev.vaadin.com/).

If the code above works, the problem is in your code then (in this case, share with us more of your code - you can even share whole class for).

Comment: I've run some tests and found out that i get the exception only after recovering the colorpicker after a relogg(restore Preferences) befor that it works normaly.

Comment: What do you mean by " recovering the colorpicker after a relogg(restore Preferences)", could you share your code? that could be more explicit and accurate. You copy/paste your code here: http://pastebin.com/